# How do you allow a role to assign other users roles - but only specific roles?

Tags: users

I'm creating a "level'ing" role system on my page. At a certain role (Full Member) the user must be able to assign someone with the role level 5 the new role level 6 manually once a dialogue is complete.

How can you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Role Delegation](https://drupal.org/project/role_delegation) is what you're looking for.

> For each role, **Role Delegation** provides a new assign ROLE role
>   permission to allow the assignment of that role.

[image]